# Change the background colour of YouTube Video embed

Tags: html, css, background, youtube

I was wondering if there's any way to change the background-colour of the YouTube screen which appears when the embedded video is initially loading (image attached below)? Currently, it has a black background colour which I wanted to change to white; I tried adding `theme=light` to the URL but that didn't help. I also searched for this option inside the YouTube Embedded Players and Player Parameters document but couldn't find anything related to this. This is how my video embed code looks like:

```
<iframe width="770" height="434" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/(video code)?theme=light&modestbranding=1&autohide=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&rel=0&vq=hd1080" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

[Google YouTube themes have been deprecated](https://developers.google.com/youtube/player_parameters?hl=en#theme):

> This parameter indicates whether the embedded player will display player controls (like a play button or volume control) within a dark or light control bar. This parameter has been deprecated for HTML5 players, which always use the dark theme.

Answer (score 0):

This is such a massive pain that only black is supported.

A bigger problem I've always had is it's almost impossible to set a width and height that rounds exactly on all screens to avoid black bars on left / top / right / bottom. These can be especially apparent on 2x and 3x screens or when using a percentage for the width.

I'm talking specifically about 1 or 2 pixels of black on one or more sides, not the large letter-boxing. So I've set the video to 16x9 aspect ratio but it doesn't round exactly to an exact number of pixels.

Have often had to add an `.overlay` layer on top of the iframe with something like:

```
overlay
{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;

    // knock out nasty borders
    outline: 2px solid white !important;
    outline-offset: -1px;

    pointer-events: none;
}
```

If only we could set the background to white it might help fix this :-(

Answer (score 0):

This is very annoying,

For anyone who seek for an easy workaround to hide the 2px black bezels,
I used a similar solution as [Simon_Weaver](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16940/simon-weaver) metioned earlier.
I simply added a pseudo element (:before) to the iframe's parent container, and it's working like a charm, no bezels whatsoever.

```css
.vid-container {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%;
    height: 0;
  }
    
.vid-container:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    outline: 4px solid #fff;
    outline-offset: -2px;
    pointer-events: none;
  }
    
.vid-container iframe{
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
  }
```

Answer (score -2):

Hack would be to hide the video with another div.

```
<iframe id="myvideo" width="770" height="434" src="//www.youtube.com/embed/TIfAkOBMf5A" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="myloadscreen" style="width:770px;height:434px;position:relative;top:-438px;background-color:#fff;background-image: url('https://i.stack.imgur.com/h6viz.gif');background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:center;left:0px;"></div>
```

See this JSFiddle [JSFiddle.net/3mzfzm76/](http://jsfiddle.net/3mzfzm76/).

Then, when it loads hide the div.

Comment: That demo never renders in the jsfiddle example :(

Comment: Fiddle both is missing a `);` at the end of the JS, and does not have jQuery loaded.